# Can't use pip install

Tags: python-3.x, linux

When ever I try to pip install anything this error always comes up again and again. Idk what's wrong. Please help :)

OS: Linux
Python version: 3.8.2

Error highlight:

```
Thanks to:
%(__credits__)s""" % globals()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Full proper error:

```
pip help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/root/.local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3252, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3235, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3277, in _initialize_master_working_set
    tuple(
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3278, in <genexpr>
    dist.activate(replace=False)
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2785, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2284, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2217, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "/home/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pygoogle/google.py", line 118
    print """PyGoogle %(__version__)s
%(__copyright__)s
released %(__date__)s

Thanks to:
%(__credits__)s""" % globals()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntaxThanks to:
%(__credits__)s""" % globals()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Edit: pip3 gives the very same error.

Comment: `pip` is for python 2.X. `pip3` is for python 3.X. If you don't have `pip3` then install with `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: @SerafimDahl pip3 gives the same error unfortunately.

Comment: And if you reinstall it? That may help to also install missing dependencies: `apt update` followed by `apt install --reinstall python3-pip`

Comment: @SerafimDahl Tried it 2-3 times still is not helping :/

Comment: what Linux do you use?

Comment: Uninstall `pygoogle` and try `pip3 help` again. Others have had issues with `pygoogle` (which is the last module in the error report)

Comment: @SerafimDahl Ahh I tried to do exactly that but pip isn't working so when I try pip uninstall pygoogle it fucks up :/

Comment: Note all the packages you need so you can reinstall them later and then use the fact that pip installs a virtual environment for its packages, `virtualenv --clear MYENV`

Comment: You might have to point at the executable `.local/bin/virtualenv --clear MYENV`

Comment: Did you solve it? If not, I have a (rather radical) solution.

Comment: Not yet. Suggest @SerafimDahl

Comment: I think I will have to work with a virtual environment till this is fixed Oof

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on my own Python3 installation as I don't use it for the moment. This is a rather radical solution:

1. Note which packages are installed with `pip` either by looking in
   `.local/bin/` and `.local/lib/pythonxxx/`, where `xxx` might be `3.8`
   or simply move them out of the way. I copied them to a temporary
   directory, not to move them back but just to keep in mind what was
   there.
2. If you didn't move them, remove what is in
   `.local/bin`and `.local/lib/python*`
3. Download `https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
4. Run `python3 get-pip.py`

You now have a clean python3 pip environment and can populate it with
whatever is missing using `pip3`.

Answer (score 0):

Which Linux distro are you running? I learned recently that RHEL doesn’t play nicely with a simple `pip install <module name>`. It’s recommended to run it as `python3 -m pip3 install <module name>`.